# at run time application responses a null point exception but debug time it works properly

Tags: android, android-volley, google-maps-android-api-2, android-json, android-googleapiclient

I am a beginner to android development and i am building an application related to map creating the route. the lat long data are taken from the php API. the problem is when i debug the program it works perfectly fine but when i run the application it show the null point exception.Please suggest me what i can do..

```
public class Driver extends AppCompatActivity{

    GoogleMap map;
    GPSTracker gps;
    String longitude;
    String latitude;
    String url;
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    SupportMapFragment fm;
    LinearLayout layout;
    ArrayList<String> truck = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<LatLng> truck_latlong = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    ArrayList<String> disposail = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<LatLng> disposail_latlong = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int mMode = 0;
    final int MODE_DRIVING = 0;
    final int MODE_BICYCLING = 1;
    final int MODE_WALKING = 2;
    public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "phone";
    public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "success";
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myappLogin";
    private String Data_Url="http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/Android/driver_work.php";
    private String Truck_url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/Android/trucks.php";
    public String Disposal_url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/Android/disposal_bins.php";
    private String COMPLETE_STATUS = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/Android/driver_work_complete.php";

    Config config = new Config();
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    ArrayList<Marker> arraymarker= new ArrayList<Marker>();
    LatLng origin;
    LatLng dest;
    private Marker maps;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    //        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.tvlayout);
    //        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    //        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //            @Override
    //            public void onClick(View view) {
    //                complete_status();
    //
    //
    //            }
    //        });


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        truck_info();
        disposal_info();

        driver_response();





    }
    public void complete_status()
    {

    }
    //    @Override
    //    public void onRefresh() {
    //
    //        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    //            @Override
    //            public void run() {
    //                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    //
    //                driver_response();
    ////
    //            }
    //        }, 4000);
    //    }


    private void logout(){
        //Creating an alert dialog to confirm logout
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        //Getting out sharedpreferences
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        //Getting editor
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        //Puting the value false for loggedin
                        editor.putBoolean(LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

                        //Putting blank value to email
                        editor.putString(EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"");

                        //Saving the sharedpreferences
                        editor.commit();

                        //Starting login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Driver.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    }
                });

        //Showing the alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    public void truck_info()
    {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Truck_url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        truck_Json(response);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
    public void truck_Json(JSONArray array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);


                String truck_no = json.getString("truck_id");
                truck.add(truck_no);
                String capacity = json.getString("capacity");
                String truck_lat = json.getString("latitude");
                String truck_long = json.getString("longitude");

                LatLng mlstlong = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(truck_lat), Double.parseDouble(truck_long));
                truck_latlong.add(mlstlong);

            }catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void disposal_info()
    {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Disposal_url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        disposal_Json(response);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
    public void disposal_Json(JSONArray array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);


                String disposial_id = json.getString("disposal_bin_id");
    //                truck.add(truck_no);
                disposail.add(disposial_id);

                String disposial_lat = json.getString("latitude");
                String disposial_long = json.getString("longitude");

                LatLng mlstlong = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(disposial_lat), Double.parseDouble(disposial_long));
                disposail_latlong.add(mlstlong);

            }catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


    public void driver_response()
       {

           Intent i = getIntent();
           final String str = i.getStringExtra("phone");
           TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
           tv.setText(str);


           StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Data_Url,
                   new Response.Listener<String>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onResponse(String s) {

                         if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Work is not been alloted yet"))
                         {
                             layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.maplayout);
                             layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                             fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                             TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                             tv.setText(s);

                         }
                           else{

                             driver_request(s);
    //                             truck_info();
                             routeCreate();


                             fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View view) {
                                     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Driver.this);
                                     alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("If you have completed your work then press Yes");
                                     alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

    //                                                     complete_status();

                                                 }
                                             });

                                     alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                                             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                                 }
                                             });

                                     //Showing the alert dialog
                                     AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                     alertDialog.show();



                                 }
                             });


                         }


    //
                       }
                   },
                   new Response.ErrorListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                           //Dismissing the progress dialog
    //                        loading.dismiss();

                           //Showing toast
                           Toast.makeText(Driver.this, "error to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                   }){
               @Override
               protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {





                   Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<>();

                   params.put(Config.KEY_PHONE, str);



                   //returning parameters
                   return params;
               }
           };

           //Creating a Request Queue
           RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

           //Adding request to the queue
           requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

       }
      public void driver_request(String s) {


          JSONArray array = null;
          try {
              array = new JSONArray(s);

          for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject json = null;
              try {
                  json = array.getJSONObject(i);



                  String area = json.getString("area");
                  String latitude = json.getString("latitude");
                  String longitude = json.getString("longitude");

                  final String truck_id = json.getString("truck_id");
                  for(int j=0;j<truck.size();j++)
                  {
                      String truck_value = truck.get(j);
                      if(truck_id.equals(truck_value))
                      {
                          map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(truck_latlong.get(j)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_truck)));
                          config.setLatLng(truck_latlong.get(j));
                      }
                  }

                  String disposial_id = json.getString("disposal_bin_id");
                  for (int k=0;k<disposail.size();k++)
                  {
                      String disposal_value = disposail.get(k);
                      if(disposial_id.equals(disposal_value))
                      {
                          map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(disposail_latlong.get(k)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_green_bin)));
                          config.setDisposail_latlng(disposail_latlong.get(k));
                      }
                  }


                  LatLng dest = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude),Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                 maps =  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dest).title("latlong").snippet(dest.toString()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_red_bin1)));
                  arraymarker.add(maps);
                  map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dest, 14));
                  map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

                      @Override
                      public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker markers) {
                          for(int j=0;j<arraymarker.size();j++) {
                              if (markers.equals(arraymarker.get(j))) {
                                  Intent i = getIntent();

                                  final String str = i.getStringExtra("phone");
                                  final LatLng latLng = markers.getPosition();
                                  Double lat = latLng.latitude;
                                  Double lon = latLng.longitude;
                                  final String lats = lat.toString();
                                  final String lons = lon.toString();
                                  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Driver.this);
                                  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Confirm??");
                                  alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {


                                                  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, COMPLETE_STATUS,
                                                          new Response.Listener<String>() {

                                                              @Override
                                                              public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                                  Toast.makeText(Driver.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                              }
                                                          },
                                                          new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                              @Override
                                                              public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                                                  Toast.makeText(Driver.this, "error to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                              }
                                                          }) {
                                                      @Override
                                                      protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


                                                          Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<>();

                                                          params.put(Config.KEY_PHONE, str);
                                                          params.put("lat", lats);
                                                          params.put("lon", lons);
                                                          params.put("truck",truck_id);



                                                          //returning parameters
                                                          return params;
                                                      }
                                                  };

                                                  //Creating a Request Queue
                                                  RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Driver.this);

                                                  //Adding request to the queue
                                                  requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


                                              }
                                          });

                                  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                              }
                                          });

                                  //Showing the alert dialog
                                  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                  alertDialog.show();

                              }
                          }



                          return false;
                      }
                  });



                  marker(dest);


              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }


          }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }

    private void marker(LatLng point)
    {

        markerPoints.add(config.getLatLng());
        markerPoints.add(config.getDisposail_latlng());
        markerPoints.add(point);

        }
     public void routeCreate()
     {
         if (markerPoints.size() >=2) {
             origin = markerPoints.get(0);
             dest = markerPoints.get(1);

             String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);
             DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
             downloadTask.execute(url);

         }

     }

    public String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {


        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
        String str_dest ="destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;






        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        String waypoints = "";


        for(int  i=2;i<markerPoints.size();i++)
        {

            LatLng point = (LatLng)markerPoints.get(i);
            if(i==2)
                waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true|";
            waypoints += point.latitude +"," +point.longitude + "|";
        }
            // Building the parameters to the web service
    //        String parameters = "waypoints=optimize:true|"+"&"+str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+"alternatives=true"+"&"+sensor+"&"+"mode=driving"+"&"+"key=AIzaSyBM9huE4dOMUE_tBHNaibKd_8nOexVCnag";
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+waypoints+"&"+"mode=Driving"+"&"+"key=AIzaSyAAhlkzSggXQrO0ojRw4v_JXh0hNAhgAWE";
            // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
      url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


        return url;
    }

    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer,  List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result)         {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(3);
                //lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

                // Changing the color polyline according to the mode
                if (mMode == MODE_DRIVING)
                    lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
    //                else if (mMode == MODE_BICYCLING)
    //                    lineOptions.color(Color.GREEN);
                else if (mMode == MODE_WALKING)
                    lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            }

            if (result.size() < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_driver, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

           logout();
            return false;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    }
```

Comment: on which line you are getting error?

Comment: @Amy   String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
        String str_dest ="destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

Comment: @Amy 
when I am debug my application its working but after debug when I again run it show nullpoint exception because the value which I set is not coming at run time..
        markerPoints.add(config.getLatLng());
        markerPoints.add(config.getDisposail_latlng());

Comment: @dhananjaysingh can you please add your logcat here

Comment: try to put `routeCreate` method from outside Post request

Comment: @Muhammad Hamza Shahid

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'double com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng.latitude' on a null object reference
at com.example.dhananjay.intelligentbin.Activity.Driver.getDirectionsUrl(Driver.java:620)
at com.example.dhananjay.intelligentbin.Activity.Driver.routeCreate(Driver.java:609)
at com.example.dhananjay.intelligentbin.Activity.Driver$7.onResponse(Driver.java:327)
 at com.example.dhananjay.intelligentbin.Activity.Driver$7.onResponse(Driver.java:310)

Comment: @Amy 
I can't do it because after response i can create route, points come after response..

Comment: @dhananjaysingh add if(point!=null) in while loop after if(i==2) in getDirectionsUrl() it will avoid NullPointerException

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaShahid
     1:    markerPoints.add(config.getLatLng()); 
     2:    markerPoints.add(config.getDisposail_latlng());

here the value is not coming.. at run time but debug time its working showing all the value.. Its something API problem aur my code not working ???

Comment: @dhananjaysingh according to your log the error is at waypoints += point.latitude +"," +point.longitude + "|"; here the point is null in any of the iteration of while loop so the solution is to put a IF statment like if(point!=null) so the code should run for iteration where point is not null